# Laravel - How to Resolve whereDate function issue

Tags: laravel

I have this code in Laravel-5.8

```
$currentDate = Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d');

$currentstatus = HrLeaveRequest::select('leave_status')->whereDate('resumption_date, '<=', $currentDate)->whereIn('leave_status', [1, 3, 4])->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')->first();
```

$currentDate = 2021-05-10

$resumption_date = 2021-05-12

But when I dd($currentstatus), I got null

How do I resolve this?

Thanks

Comment: because your resumption_date is greater and in `whereDate('resumption_date, '<=', $currentDate)` you are passing less than.

Comment: As Shahrukh said, change `'<='` to `'>='.`

Comment: Make sure you have matching record for given condition, may be due to other clauses your are not getting data.

Answer (score -2):

change `whereDate` to `where` , you have filed `resumption_date` not `date`

Comment: `WherDate` is a method and you can read about it [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#where-clauses)